# Smallest tooltip script (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, tooltip

Does anyone know one?

All the ones I found on the web use either jQuery or Prototype, which I don't want to load just to show some tooltips.

Comment: You're probably aware the html title attribute adds tooltips to things in all modern browsers but I just thought I'd point it out in case you weren't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

qTip is the smallest tooltip library I know (only 2K filesize) and does not require jQuery or external plugins. In addition, it's one of few add-ons that are compatible with IE 5.5 and on.

**qTip**: http://qrayg.com/learn/code/qtip

For more tooltip plugins (some of which *do* require jQuery):

**Reference**: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/12/tooltips-scripts-ajax-javascript-css-dhtml/